# Does the 6502 put FF in the stack pointer register as soon as it gets power for the first time?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm reading about the 6502 processor's instruction set from the many links at 6502.org, and one tutorial states:

> The stack pointer (S) points to a byte on Page 1, that is, to a byte whose address is from 0100 to 01FF, where the last two digits are supplied by S. When a byte is pushed on the stack, it is written at the address in S, and then S is decremented.

The S register is 1 byte, so it obviously holds a value from 00 to FF, but since it decrements upon pushes, when nothing has yet been pushed on, it must start at FF. Does the physical hardware (transistors) in the chip set all the bits in that register to '1' when the chip gets its first breath of power?

I just like to know the low-level details.

Comment: What's the over/under on somebody actually knowing this, I wonder...:)

Answer (score 4):

Every ROM based on 6502 and compatible code I've ever seen initializes the stack pointer (`LDX #$FF`, `TXS`) during the RESET routine.  You should too.

It's possible later 6502 revisions (i.e. 65C02 in the Apple II) do explicitly initialize it, as well as the 65816 16-bit variants and later.

I would bet significantly that `.S` is a random value on power up on the original 6502 and the 6510 in the Commodore 64, and probably even the 2A07 in the NES.

Generally any 6502 reset routine also begins with the following, generally as the first two instructions:

```
SEI ;disable interrupts (set interrupt disable flag)
CLD ;turn decimal mode off
```

Comment: The Apple I and II resets do not set the SP, actually.  It's probably safer to say most ROMs set it, but it's not actually required in most cases.

Comment: Interesting ... I guess honestly if you are going to use it as a stack for JSR, PLA, PHA, etc. and never reference it directly as memory with LDA, etc. (and indeed have 256 bytes of RAM there - the Atari 2600 for example only has the 128 bytes from $80-$FF) - it doesn't really matter where it "starts." - unless you want to "clear" it sometime.  Bet Woz just wanted to save 3 bytes in his ROM.

Answer (score 4):

If you watch Michael Steil's presentation on reverse engineering the 6502 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWqBmmPQP40), you'll see at around 42:15 that he explains what happens when RESET occurs.  As part of the RESET handling, the 6502 actually does push the PC and P values.  The stack pointer starts at 0x100 and after pushing those three bytes, ends up at 0x1fd because of that.

Comment: I saw 42:15 but what doesnt make sense is that PC would require two pushes (as its a 16 bit value) and P one push (as its an 8 bit value). You end up with 0x1FC. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the stack pointer effectively starts at `0x00`. So by pushing a 16-bits value and an 8-bits value (PC and P), it gets decremented three times from `0x00`, ending up at `0xFD`.

Answer (score 2):

http://forum.6502.org/viewtopic.php?t=468&sid=ccdf15a560f1520a347ba896ae89767f claim that it's not specified.

http://whats.all.this.brouhaha.com/2011/07/07/stack-usage-in-the-apple-1-monitor/ also claims that it's not specified and further that it doesn't matter if you don't care about the exact position of the stack within that page. Wherever it starts it will wrap round, so as long as you don't use more than 256 bytes of stack you're fine.

http://visual6502.org/JSSim/ which is a transistor-level simulation of actual hardware appears to boot up with SP set to FD; you could probably trace the actual registers there and determine if that's deliberate or just a coincidence.

(In that context "monitor" means a low level control program rather than a display)

Comment: re "it doesn't matter if you don't care about the exact position of the stack": if you use the stack to store locals or function arguments, you will care about the exact position of the stack. E.g. reading the second local from the stack to the accumulator (TSX / LDA $00FF,X) will fail if the stack pointer is at 0 because you will read from $00FF instead of $01FF. This can easily happen if the stack starts at too low an address. This issue only applies if you access the stack with absolute indexed addressing, though.

Answer (score -1):

For software applications, it usually doesn't matter. If your program will not return to basic you can do as has been said above, which is take control of SP yourself. If you will return to basic then you should be sure you return with the stack in the same condition it was in before your program started or BASIC will crash.

The response by Snarfblam above is technically misleading, firstly because "reading the second local" has no specific meaning, but also because with TSX, LDA $00FF,X will Never LDA from any address higher than $01FE since the max for X is $FF: $00FF + FF = $01FE. Also, if you want the accumulator to read the previous value pushed to the stack, PLA will suffice.